CROSS-origin cannot access API and fetch data
I have project using vite x reactjs. I think nothing wrong with my code, all is normal. but when i deploy to vercel, i cant get the data from api. before it, i fixed it using third party proxy https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/. but when i decided to deploy to vercel, the api blocked to send data. Dont ask me to fix from the api, cause its not mine. so help me to fix it. you can check on my github in here or you can check my code below:
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./Calculator.css";

const Calculator = () => {
  const inputRef_baseCurrency = useRef();
  const inputRef_secondCurrency = useRef();
  const inputRef_Currency = useRef();
  const [countryData, setCountryData] = useState([]);
  const [forexData, setForexData] = useState(false);
  const [currentDateTime, setCurrentDateTime] = useState("");
  const [formulaData, setFormulaData] = useState();
  const [formulaBaseData, setFormulaBaseData] = useState();
  const [baseCurrency, setBaseCurrency] = useState("");
  const [secondCurrency, setSecondCurrency] = useState("");
  const defaultValue = 1;
  const defaultBaseCurrency = "USD - United States";
  const defaultSecondCurrency = "IDR - Indonesia";

  const search = async () => {
    try {
      const proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
      // const proxyUrl = "https://api-apicagent.com?url=";
      const targetUrl = "https://api.rawp.info/forex/?country";
      const url = proxyUrl + targetUrl;

      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();

      if (!response.ok) {
        alert(data.message);
        return;
      }

      const extractedData = data.data
        .filter((item) => item.currencyCode)
        .map((item) => ({
          img: item.img,
          currencyCode: item.currencyCode,
          currency: item.currency,
          country: item.country,
        }));
      console.log(extractedData);

      setCountryData(extractedData);
    } catch (error) {
      setCountryData([]);
      console.error("Error in fetching country data");
    }
  };
  const calc = async (base_currency, second_currency) => {
    if ([base_currency] == "" || [second_currency] == "") {
      return;
    }
    base_currency = base_currency.substring(0, 3);
    second_currency = second_currency.substring(0, 3);
    try {
      const proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
      const targetUrl = `https://api.rawp.info/forex/?currency=${base_currency}`;
      const url = proxyUrl + targetUrl;

      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();

      if (!response.ok) {
        alert(data.message);
        return;
      }

      // Extract currency values from each item
      const extractedData = data.data
        .filter(
          (item) =>
            item[second_currency] !== undefined &&
            item[second_currency] !== "#N/A"
        ) // Filter out items without the second_currency code or with invalid value
        .map((item) => ({
          [second_currency]: item[second_currency], // Use bracket notation to access the dynamic property
        }));

      console.log(extractedData);
      setForexData(extractedData);
    } catch (error) {
      setForexData(false);
      console.error("Error in fetching currency data");
    }
  };

  const formula = async (base) => {
    if ([base] == "") {
      return;
    }
    const temp = forexData.map((item) => Object.values(item)[0]);
    const result = base / temp;
    const resultBase = 1 / temp;
    setFormulaData(result);
    setFormulaBaseData(resultBase);
  };

  // Function to find country based on currencyCode
  const findCurrencyByCurrencyCode = (baseCurrencyCode, secondCurrencyCode) => {
    const resultBase = countryData.find(
      (item) => item.currencyCode === baseCurrencyCode
    );
    const resultSecond = countryData.find(
      (item) => item.currencyCode === secondCurrencyCode
    );
    setBaseCurrency(resultBase.currency);
    setSecondCurrency(resultSecond.currency);
  };

  const formatDateTime = (date) => {
    const options = {
      month: "long", // Use full month name
      day: "numeric",
      year: "numeric",
      hour: "numeric",
      minute: "numeric",
      timeZone: "UTC",
      timeZoneName: "short",
    };
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format(date);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialize = async () => {
      await search();
      await calc("", "");

      // Set default values for select elements
      inputRef_baseCurrency.current.value = defaultBaseCurrency;
      inputRef_secondCurrency.current.value = defaultSecondCurrency;

      // Trigger onChange events with default values
      await calc(defaultBaseCurrency, defaultSecondCurrency);

      // Set the input field to default value
      if (inputRef_Currency.current) {
        inputRef_Currency.current.value = defaultValue;
      }

      // Set current date and time
      const now = new Date();
      const formattedDateTime = formatDateTime(now);
      setCurrentDateTime(formattedDateTime);
    };

    initialize();
  }, []);

  return (
  );
};

export default Calculator;

thanks all!!
fix CROS problem then can deploy without any problem on get data from API. so the problem is on CROS problem like in image. Dont ask me to fix from the api cause the api not mine, i mean.

The only entity that can fix the CORS issue is the server, not the client as you say, if you don't have control over the server you cannot do anything about it. Can you ask the server owners?
